# Flask insert and get id snippet

Tags: python, flask

Hello so I am building a simple rest using Flask and I am using this function:

```
def insert(table, fields=(), values=()):
    # g.db is the database connection
    cur = g.db.cursor()
    query = 'INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)' % (
        table,
        ', '.join(fields),
        ', '.join(['?'] * len(values))
    )
    cur.execute(query, values)
    g.db.commit()
    id = cur.lastrowid
    cur.close()
    return id
```

I can't actually get it to work with my code:

```
t = request.form['title']
e = request.form['extension']
insert('books', (id, title, extension), [NULL, t, e])
```

it says that title is not defined. What is the proper way of calling the function?

Comment: in your html form, is there a field with `name="title"`? also did try renaming your variable `t` into `title` and `e` into `extension`?

Comment: Post exact error message you are getting @ CONSOLE.

Answer (score 1):

`id`, `title`, and `extension` appear to be your column names and need to be treated as strings, not variables. `NULL` will also give you problems. You want to use `None` instead.

```
insert('books', ('id', 'title', 'extension'), [None, t, e])
```